# Implement RequestBodyAdvice and ResponseBodyAdvice<T> in one class

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I want to access HTTP Request and response payload in one place of code. I try to implementing *RequestBodyAdvice* and *ResponseBodyAdvice* in separated classes and it worked fine, but in two separated places of code.
Then I try to implement these two in one class but only methods of either *RequestBodyAdvice* or *ResponseBodyAdvice* invoked. for example in below code only *beforeBodyRead* and *afterBodyRead*(these are owned by *RequestBodyAdvice*) invoked;and it is strange for me that these two invoked two times for every request!(at the time that I implement these interfaces in separated classes every method invoked only once):

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomResponseBodyAdviceAdapter implements RequestBodyAdvice, ResponseBodyAdvice<Object>{
    public CustomResponseBodyAdviceAdapter() {
    }
    @Override
    public boolean supports(MethodParameter methodParameter,
                            Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> aClass) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Object beforeBodyWrite(Object o,
                                  MethodParameter methodParameter,
                                  MediaType mediaType,
                                  Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> aClass,
                                  ServerHttpRequest serverHttpRequest,
                                  ServerHttpResponse serverHttpResponse) {
        return o;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(MethodParameter methodParameter, Type type, Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> aClass) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public HttpInputMessage beforeBodyRead(HttpInputMessage httpInputMessage, MethodParameter methodParameter, Type type, Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> aClass) throws IOException {
        return httpInputMessage;
    }

    @Override
    public Object afterBodyRead(Object o, HttpInputMessage httpInputMessage, MethodParameter methodParameter, Type type, Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> aClass) {
        return o;
    }

    @Override
    public Object handleEmptyBody(Object o, HttpInputMessage httpInputMessage, MethodParameter methodParameter, Type type, Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> aClass) {
        return o;
    }
}
```

I want to implement these two interfaces in one class in the way that all methods invoke correctly.

Update: Spring boot version is **2.0.1.RELEASE**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's already implemented [under the hood of Spring](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestResponseBodyAdviceChain.java).

The class has private-package access but you can copy it and implement both `supports()` methods according to your requirements.

**Updated**

The PoC you can find [here](https://github.com/rawmind/spring-body-processing)

Comment: Korov Did you test? I mean copy and paste the implementation? I tried, but the problem still exists!

Comment: Yes. It works for me. Did you try it for bare spring boot project?

Comment: are the request and response worked simuntanously? Even for me it is working fine, but only response or request

Comment: Yes, update your question and describe what exactly doesn’t work. Also, it would be could to see the whole code

Comment: Helpful* (not “could”)

Comment: Another section is nothing but a regular spring boot app that has some controller and service. I explained the problem with the question. Please read the question text Which spring boot version you are using?

Comment: I'm using `2.3.1` Also, I updated the answer and added my code. Also, here's my [output](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/3339076/95788195-bb097200-0ce3-11eb-93d7-53b99bca0a7e.png) for `curl -d "a body" localhost:8080/check   `

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got that the problem is for Spring boot version **2.0.1.RELEASE**!
I tested the code that @Andrei Kovrov sent as PoC, It was working fine. But at the time that I changed the spring boot version to 2.0.1.RELEASE, it behaves crazily(Same code).